# React native state is not updating for an array

Tags: react-native, state, use-effect, state-management, react-state-management

I'm trying to load data into an array by updating the initial state of it, but the state doesn't get updated and it return the original empty state.

Below is snapshot of the state initialisation, use effect and the arrow function to update the state.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    show: false,
    isFocused: false,
    ......
    rewardsCards: [] // this is the state that needs to get updated.
})

useEffect(() => {
    getRewardsCards

    checkPermissionsAsync()
    getMembersCards()
    props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', payload => {
        getMembersCards()
    })
}, [state.refreshing])

const getRewardsCards = async () => {
    console.log('getRewardsCards running')
    let rewardscards = await membershipProviderService.getMembershipProvider()
    console.log('rewardscards', JSON.stringify(rewardscards, null, 2))
    setState({
        ...state,
        rewardsCards: rewardscards
    })
    console.log('rewardscards set', state.rewardsCards)
}

const ....
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you calling `getRewardCards` as a function `getRewardCards()`? From your code in the `useEffect` you are not calling it, I'm assuming it's a typo but want to double check.

Comment: @nicodp when you have noticed, I thought it might be a stupid typo. But even after calling the correct function name 'getRewardCards()' still return 'rewardscards set Array []'

Comment: If you console.log right after you have set the state, you won't see the updated value since setState is async. Try console.log outside the function and you will notice two outputs. One with the old value, one with the updated one in the next render cycle.

Comment: Thank you @DavidScholz, I really appreciated for pointing it out! All updated :)